# Use variable in call to subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Python in the build of a Qt application. The Python script gets called in different PCs and these PCs might have different number of CPUs. To take advantage of that, in the make step I 'm specifying the number of CPUs:

```
subprocess.call(["mingw32-make",
                 "-j4"], shell=True, env=environ)
```

To check the number of CPUs I do:

```
n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

How do I replace the `-j4` by `n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it in using *str.format*:

```
n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
subprocess.call(["mingw32-make", "-j{}".format(n)], env=environ)
```

Comment: Need to remove the minus sign at the end of `subprocess.call(["mingw32-make", "-j{}".format(n)], env=environ) –`

Comment: And don't use `shell=True`.

Comment: @Brian, which minus sign?

Comment: It was removed. Random typo minus sign at the end of the line.